# Android Bluetooth Get Bonded Devices

Tags: android, textview, android-arrayadapter

I can't figure out how to get my bonded devices on a list through this code :

```
bt_scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            // If there are paired devices
            if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                // Loop through paired devices
                for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                    // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                    mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                }
            }

                                                        }});}
```

I don't know how to get it in a text view or a list view one the same layout or even in another if it's possible.
I'd like to make a connection to one of the found devices but that's a whole other story.

(Here is my full code if it helps : http://pastie.org/4582924)

Thanks a lot !

Comment: If only you want to show your arrayAdapter findings into a ListView you just set the arrayAdapter to the listView control. I did a simple video on adding items to a list view via an adapter, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61WvMzaihwU&feature=plcp you may skip till minute 4 more or less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I agree with Vishwa, the Bluetooth Chat Application is very helpful, I have done same(like yours) kind of development, here is my code,

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/title_new_devices"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#666" android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/new_devices" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity Class

```
private static BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;
private static ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;

private static ArrayList<String> nameList = null;
private static ArrayList<String> macList = null;

private static ListView newDevicesListView = null;



        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);


        filter = new IntentFilter( BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED );
        this.registerReceiver( mReceiver, filter );

        // Get the local Bluetooth adapter
        mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

BroadCastReceiver Class

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            try
            {
                String action = intent.getAction();

                // When discovery finds a device
                if ( BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action) ) 
                {
                    // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    String deviceName = device.getName();
                    String deviceAddress = device.getAddress();

                    if ( !nameList.contains( deviceName.trim() + " " + deviceAddress.trim() ) )
                    {
                        nameList.add( deviceName.trim() + " " + deviceAddress.trim() );
                        macList.add( deviceAddress.trim() + "&" + ConstantCodes.TIME + ConstantCodes.EQUALS + DateUtility.getDateTime() );
                    }

//                  System.out.println ( device.getName() );
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } 
                else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) 
                {
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else if ( BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals( action ) )
                {
//                  nameList.clear();
                }
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                System.out.println ( "Broadcast Error : " + e.toString() );
            }
        }
    };
```

The code will search for the active bluetooth device and display it in the listView.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Bluetooth Chat application provided in the Android SDK, it provides a clean way of displaying the phones you are currently paired with.

It also provides a BluetoothChatService class that you can easily adapt to connect found devices.